# How to map aspects to reviews in sentiment analysis?

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, zomato-api

I am doing sentiment analysis on the aspects of food reviews in python . If the review is  Eg : "Biryani was good and the atmosphere was bad"  , it should be tagged as {[food,1],[ambience,-1]} (i.e) Food should be mapped to briyani and ambience to atmosphere .

Could you please help me to solve this ?? Is there any pre defined dictionaries in python to handle these food reviews to map them ??

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any specific food-review sentiment analysis tools/libraries for Python. But this [website](https://www.iflexion.com/blog/sentiment-analysis-python)  lists and reviews a few popular, general-purpose sentiment analysis libraries for Python.